# Rcpp Eigen accessing a row from a SparseMatrix

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

I am using a sparse matrix from Eigen as a data structure for some of my functions. My function will iterate over the rows of a sparse matrix and perform some operations. I am trying to access the row of a sparse matrix as a SparseVector, but for some reason that causes R to crash.

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;
using Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix;
using Eigen::SparseVector;
using Eigen::Triplet;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace Eigen;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::SparseVector<double> getSparseVec(const Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix<double>& X) {
  return X.row(1);
}
```

The return type of .row() seems to be a ConstRowXpr, but I don't know how to get that into the form of a SparseVector, and I've been unable to find the doc page for ConstRowXpr

Comment: Your example should work fine, although extracting a row from a column-major matrix is inefficient. How does your code crash? Are you sure X has at least two rows (in your example)?

Comment: There is no native type `SparseVector` for R. Look at the existing examples of how the `S4` types from the `Matrix` package are used for _matrices_ and set up something similar.

Comment: Short story @JCWong, to use `SparseVector` you need to setup the as and wrap converters for the `Matrix` R package's [`sparseVector` class](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparseVector-class.html).